# Truncate specific number of characters in SQL cells

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have `Description` column in a table

```
   Description 
  ---------------
    AA Check 
    B1 Check
    RD/AA Check 
    WD_FA Examine 
    FF Examine 
    AA Pass 
    B2 Check 
    Examine
```

The desired output

```
    Description 
  ---------------
    Check 
    Examine  
    Pass
```

Basically a case statement where it truncates from the left side of the cell. NOTE that the list goes on with different names and conditions, and some cells do not need modification (like the last row), so something similar to a case statement but not returning NULL if I did not specify the condition 
Thank you

Comment: How does the data go from 8 rows to 3?

Comment: The "check"s, "Examine"s and "Pass"es got grouped

Comment: How do you decide which values to remove and which to keep?

Comment: Do you want to strip off the data after the 1st space or to get the last word if there are multiple spaces?

Comment: are you after of the last word or stripping off the first word? you need to concise here

Comment: Yes, basically strip off the first data before a space. So a statement where it strips off everything in the beginning until reaching a space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This removes the data up to the 1st space

```
case when x like '% %' 
     then substring(x, charindex(' ', x) +1, 8000)
     else x
end

'AA Examine Device' -> 'Examine Device'
```

And this extracts the last word:

```
case when x like '% %' 
     then right(x, charindex(' ', reverse(x)) -1)
     else x
end

'AA Examine Device' -> 'Device'
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer based on his comments to my answer. +1 from me. However, it doesn't work for, odd examples like he posted in my comment, like 'Keep This'

Answer (score 2):

Following the white space that you have, and using `DISTINCT`, this gets the last word following a white space or returns the word if it's the only word.

```
declare @Description table (Description varchar(64))
insert into @Description
values
('AA Check'),
('B1 Check'),
('RD/AA Check'),
('WD_FA Examine'),
('FF Examine'),
('AA Pass'),
('B2 Check'),
('Examine')

select distinct
    right([Description],len([Description]) - charindex(' ',[Description]))
from @Description
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to have multiple considitons? Some of the data I have have two words, not only one (i.e. AA Examine Device) and I want it to return (Examine Device)

Comment: The beginning of the string is always upper case. Also, the parts I want to trim are always capitalized. Below are some examples

Comment: If you will always split it at the first space, then it is easy. However, if you have that phrase "Examine Device" with no leading character section, the pattern matching becomes much more complex.  So far, the only pattern I see is that you are keeping the words in lower or mixed case, and removing the leading sections that are all uppercase or special characters. If that isn't a valid pattern, then I'm not sure how to match your edge cases.

Comment: AA Examine Device -> Examine Device.........D1_FF Look Up -> Look up......B3 Check Status -> Check Status

Comment: @AshA: What about `AA D1_FF Look Up`? Is such a value possible?

Comment: Yes unfortunately. The data I have access to wasn't properly formatted

Comment: I think the question is too broad now @dnoeth and unable to be coded for

Comment: @scsimon: Yep, would be easy if SQL Server supported Regular Expressions :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below :

```
select distinct substring(Description, charindex(' ', Description) + 1, len(Description))
```

Comment: What if I have multiple conditions? I can only put one condition here

Comment: close, but it will cut the `e` off `Examine` or the last character of any word that is the only word with no space in the column

Answer (score 1):

The question is too broad, but you can use something like that

```
DECLARE @Product TABLE (
    [Description] nvarchar(255),
    Condition int
);

INSERT @Product ([Description], Condition)
select 'AA Check', 1 union all
select 'B1 Check', 2 union all
select 'RD/AA Check', 3 union all
select 'WD_FA Examine', 3 union all
select 'FF Examine', 4 union all
select 'AA Pass', 1 union all
select 'B2 Check', 5 union all
select 'Examine', 6



select
[Description],
case 
when Condition = 1 then replace([Description],'AA ','')
when Condition = 2 then replace([Description],'B1 ','')
when Condition = 3 then ltrim(rtrim(right([Description],len([Description]) - 5)))
when Condition = 5 then replace([Description],'B2 ','')
when Condition = 6 then [Description]
else 
''
end as 'NewDescription'
from @Product
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [A] ( [Description] VARCHAR(100));

INSERT [A]
VALUES
---------------
( 'AA Check' )
,( 'B1 Check' )
,( 'RD/AA Check' )
,( 'WD_FA Examine' )
,( 'FF Examine' )
,( 'AA Pass' )
,( 'B2 Check' )
,( 'Examine' )
,( 'Examine Device' );

SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE
        WHEN [Description] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN LIKE '[A-Z][a-z]%' THEN
            [Description]
        WHEN [Description] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z0-9]%' THEN
            SUBSTRING([Description], CHARINDEX(' ', [Description]) + 1, 8000)
    END AS [Description]
FROM
[A];

DROP TABLE [A];
```

Comment: Considering from comments below that you could also have values like AA D1_FF you could probably extend it using regular expressions for the relevant number of spaces that you want to check to . The assumption in the code above is that the ones that you want to keep are properly camel cased

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
;WITH CTE (Column1) AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            ('    AA Check '), ('    B1 Check'), ('    RD/AA Check '), ('    WD_FA Examine '), ('    FF Examine '), 
            ('    AA Pass '), ('    B2 Check '), ('    Examine  ')
        ) AS A (Column1)
    )

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Check', Column1) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Column1, CHARINDEX('Check', Column1), 5)
    WHEN CHARINDEX('Examine', Column1) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Column1, CHARINDEX('Examine', Column1), 7)
    WHEN CHARINDEX('Pass', Column1) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Column1, CHARINDEX('Pass', Column1), 4)
    END AS Results
FROM CTE
```

It would be painful if you have a lot of variables though.